# What is the proper name of a point a long a smooth curve where the radius changes but not direction of curvature?

Tags: terminology, euclidean-geometry, curvature, curves

What you call a point a long a smooth curve where the radius changes?  When it reverses curvature, it’s an “inflection point”.  What if it doesn’t change direction, just radius?  I seem to remember another term.

Answer (score 0):

If the curvature  never changes sign,
then the region
between the line connecting 
any two points on the curve
and the curve between
those two point
is a convex region
(i.e.,
the line between
any two points
in that region
is also completely in that region.

So,
the curve itself
could be called
convex or concave,
depending on
which side it is looked at from.

As to the points themselves,
I would call them
ordinary points.

No other special name comes to mind.